# SQL query to group the data by the workflow criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query to view some project metrics
I have 2 tables.

```
WorkflowDefinition (In this the workflow definition is according to the   product land and is different for different productLaneID)
ProductLaneID | StepID | StepName | WorkflowRevisionID
4               1        RA         1
4               2        Design     1
4               3        ME         1
4               4        Tooling    1
4               5        Waiting    1
4               6        Manuf      1
4               7        Completed  1
5               1        RA         1
5               2        Concepts   1
5               3        Design     1
5               4        ME         1
5               5        Tooling    1
5               6        Waiting    1
5               7        Manuf      1
5               8        FieldTesting1
5               9        Completed  1
```

In this I want to club

```
 Step 3&4 from ProductLaneID=4 as PLES
 StepID 5&6 from ProductLaneID = 4 as Manuf

StepID 2&3 from productLaneID =5 as Design
StepID 4&5 from productLaneID =5 as PLES
StepID 6&7 from productLaneID =5 as Manufacturing


ProjectScheduleHistory
ProjectID|FromStepID|ToStepID|EnteredStepDate|ExitedStepDate
```

Now a project can go from Step 1-2 and from 2-1 and then again to 1-2
So i want to find the Date of Initial step entry and the last date of step exit.
Accordingly It will calculate the no of days in each step in terms of Design, PLES and Manuf

Result would be like

```
ProjectID | Design CompletionDate | Days in Design| PLES Comp Date | Days in PLES| Manuf Comp Date | No of Days in Manuf.
```

I have started with the following sql query.

```
select ProjectID,FromStepID,ToStepID,
[EnteredStepDate] = MIN(EnteredStepDate),
[ExitedStepDate] = MAX(ExitedStepDate),ProjectLaneID,
[DaysInStep] = SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,EnteredStepDate,ExitedStepDate)),
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(StepName,'Manufacturing             Engineering','PLES'),'Tooling','PLES'),'Concept','Design'),'Waiting On   Order','Manufacturing')StepName
from lovWorkflowDefinition
left outer join dtaProjectScheduleHistory
on FromStepID = StepID
where (StepName = 'Design' or StepName = 'PLES' or StepName =  'Manufacturing') and (ProjectLaneID=4 or ProjectLaneID=5)
group by   ProjectID,FromStepID,ToStepID,EnteredStepDate,ExitedStepDate,ProjectLaneID,StepName
```

I want to group the data according to Design, PLES and Manuf

.

Comment: The syntax looks like SQL Server so I removed the extraneous database tags for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following using conditional `CASE/WHEN` statements and derived table subquery:

```
SELECT ProjectID, Max([Step Name]) As [StepName],
       Max(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Design' THEN ExitedStepDate END) As [Design Comp Date],
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Design' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, EnteredStepDate, ExitedStepDate) END) AS [Days in Design],

       Max(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Ples' THEN ExitedStepDate END) As [PLES Comp Date],
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Ples' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, EnteredStepDate, ExitedStepDate) END) AS [Days in Design],

       Max(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Manuf' THEN ExitedStepDate END) As [Manuf Comp Date],
       Sum(CASE WHEN [Step Name] = 'Manuf' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, EnteredStepDate, ExitedStepDate) END) AS [Days in Design],
FROM 
   (SELECT proj.ProjectID, proj.FromStepID, proj.ToStepID, 
           proj.EnteredStepDate, proj.ExitedStepDate,
           CASE 
             WHEN proj.StepID IN (3, 4) AND work.ProductLaneID = 4 THEN 'Ples'
             WHEN proj.StepID IN (5, 6) AND work.ProductLaneID = 4 THEN 'Manufacturing'
             WHEN proj.StepID IN (2, 3) AND work.ProductLaneID = 5 THEN 'Design'
             WHEN proj.StepID IN (4, 5) AND work.ProductLaneID = 5 THEN 'Ples'
             WHEN proj.StepID IN (6, 7) AND work.ProductLaneID = 5 THEN 'Manufacturing'
           END  As [Step Name]
   FROM WorkflowDefinition work
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectScheduleHistory proj
   ON wrk.StepID = proj.FromStepID
   ) As dT
GROUP BY ProjectID
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, Thanks for your input. I could make this work. Appreciate your effort. Now I want to modify this to handle 1 more condition like if project goes from step 3 directly to 7 then how do we handle this situation. Same applies for other steps.

Comment: Query should still work. From what I gather, `ProjectScheduleHistory` table maintains the `FromStepID` and `ToStepID`. So just add new record for 3 and 7 to table and query joins to `WorkflowDefinition` table by `StepID`. Unless a new condition for `[Step Name]` occurs, add an additional `CASE/WHEN` statement in derived table.

Comment: Hi Parfait,Because we are doing WorkflowDefinition work
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ProjectScheduleHistory, we are getting 1 row for each ProjectLaneID which is not needed. We only need to add one more column in projScheduleHistory with StepName for from query. We only need the the data in ProjectScheduleHistory based on new WorkflowDefinition

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` clause condition in derived table to filter down the resulting records. So add whatever defines *new WorkflowDefinition*. As for `[Step Name]`, add it to the outer, main query in select and group by lines. See edit.

Comment: by doing this every column blanked out except the ProjectID.

Comment: Try aggregating `[Step Name]` then. And be sure actual records exist in `WHERE` clause condition.